# Excel: Name already exist in destination

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

After cleaning out all the names in the Name Manager list in a worksheet in Excel, I tried moving the sheet all over again and still got the pop-up message of "name already in the destination'. What am I missing please

Comment: Do you have a filter (right-upper corner) set? If yes, clean it ... Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: What spreadsheet app are you using?

Answer (score 1):

*Long back I've had similar problem and I found the reason was that some worksheets had been moved or copied from other workbooks, which have had named ranges also.*

**You can try these steps to get rid from the issue.**

1. Close all open Workbooks if any & shut down 
   Excel.
2. Restart  Excel and then open the workbook.
3. Press `Ctrl+F3` and filter the named ranges on 
   errors.
4. Delete all erroneous named ranges.
5. Finish with OK.
6. Save & close the workbook.

Now when you copy or move  sheets, you should not face that error.

**Edited:**

1. May possible you have few formulas in- 
   tagged with `Named Ranges` can't be 
   deleted so that better `RENAME` the 
   `NAMED RANGES` at  source Workbook to 
   avoid the duplicates. I think `Rename` 
   them is the  best possible solution.

Hope this also work for you.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks yes it's wonderful feeling to get 3K mark,,, ☺.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, so I'll tell you how I got rid of it.
First, click on formulas tab on the ribbon and click on Name Manager>, scroll through the list of defined names and look at what that name refers to. I had one that referred to another workbook, I deleted it, and it fixed the problem. Hope this helps you too!